# Call to a member function diff() on string in use Jalali Persian date

Tags: php, laravel, date

I have a `finish_time` column with `date` type in database. I'm using ***`Jalali`*** package to get the current *Persian Date* with this Code:

```
$now = \Morilog\Jalali\jDateTime::strftime('Y-m-d', strtotime('now'));
```

I want to know the number of days between `$now` and `finish_time`. I used this code below:

```
$now->diff($giveaway->finish_time)
```

But I get this Error

> `Call to a member function diff() on string`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: have you figure this out yet?

Answer (score 0):

**`jDateTime::strftime`** returns a formatted *`string`* so it's not possible to call `->diff()`  on your variable `$now` which is a string.

Use a carbon instance for this instead:

```
$now = \Morilog\Jalali\jDateTime::strftime('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('now'));

$_now = \Morilog\Jalali\jDateTime::createCarbonFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $now);
dd($_now->diff($giveaway->finish_time));
```

UPDATE:

Assuming `$giveaway->finish_time` returns a string like `1394/11/25 15:00:00`,
then you'll need to convert it to a `DateTime` instance

```
$finishDate = \Morilog\Jalali\jDateTime::createCarbonFromFormat(
      'Y/m/d H:i:s', $giveaway->finish_time
); 

// Change the dateTime format according to how your ->finish_time is being formatted

// then, you'll be able to get the datetime difference using
dd($_now->diff($finishDate));
```

Comment: thanks!I test it But get this Error `DateTime::diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given `

Comment: @HanieAsemi it seems, `$giveaway->finish_time` returns a *`string`*, so you'll have to convert it to a `DateTimeInterface` instance. I updated my answer